# Firebase: How do I keep track of the current user?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, sveltekit

I am using Sveltekit with a +page.js that fetches user data. How do I keep track of a user's display name and query firestore? Here is the code

```
import { collection, getDocs, limit, query, where } from "firebase/firestore";
import type { PageLoad } from "./$types";
import { db, auth } from "$lib/firebase";


export const load = (async () => {
  const collectionRef = collection(db, "users");
  if (auth.currentUser){
    const q = query(
      collectionRef,
      where("username", "==", auth.currentUser.displayName ),
      limit(1)
    );
    const snapshot = await getDocs(q);
    const data = snapshot.docs[0]?.data();
      return {
          username: data.username,
          photoURL: data.photourl,
          email: data.email,
          uuid: data.uuid
      };
  } else{
    return {

      uuid: null
    };
  }
}) satisfies PageLoad;
```

I tried using the auth.currentUser from firebase but this resulted in a 500 internal error

Comment: Firebase Auth in Sveltekit doesn't provide auth.currentUser so you'll have to save the authenticated user object in a cookie, svelte/store, or localStorage on sign in, that you can then access in your +page.js